# Why is RegExp.test() not consistent?

Tags: javascript, regex

I do not understand why the javascript `RegExp.test()` method do no return the same result every time I call it.

Given the following javascript variables

```
var opener = '<span[^>]*>';
var regexo = new RegExp('^'+opener+'$', "g");
```

I do the following:

```
alert(regexo.test('<span class="outer">')); // true
alert(regexo.test('<span class="inner">')); // false
alert(regexo.test('<span class="inner">')); // true
```

I tested it in Firefox 24.0 and IE8 with the same strange result.

Why is the result `true, false, true` instead of `true, true, true` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because you use the `g` flag. It turns the regexp object into an iterator, whose state changes with each call.

You don't need the `g` flag here, so just remove it :

```
var regexo = new RegExp('^'+opener+'$');
```

Comment: +1 `g` is used as a global modifier, on removing it might fail to satisfy any condition.  Not sure please correct me if I was wrong

Comment: @user1671639 I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment, so I don't know if you're right or not. But to be clear, I don't think there can even be a good reason to use this flag when you use the `test` function.

Comment: Was having the same issue with ".exec()".  this fixed it.  Thanks!  Kind of silly that it works this way, but ok.